# Solution to logging DB metrics using SqlAlchemy, FastAPI and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, logging, sqlalchemy, fastapi

What metrics i can get from SqlAlchemy objects on backend side if i have no access to MySQL DB server direct by ssh? In my case I need to figure out why the connection to the database freezes with the my application on FastAPI. It looks like problem on python side. I have db connection legacy code like:

```
engine = create_engine(settings.DB_URL, echo=False, pool_recycle=57400)
session_factory = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
SessionLocal = scoped_session(session_factory)

def get_db() -> Session:
    db = SessionLocal()
    logger.info(f'Something from db, session or engine to log metrics...')
    try:
        yield db
    except Exception as exc:
        db.rollback()
        logger.error(f'DBRROR: {traceback.format_exc()}')
        raise exc
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I need some metrics examples like methods which can get DB performance values to check what can be happened in my app with DB connection and work with DB. I plan to add this values to `logger.info(f'Something from db, session or engine to log metrics...')` string.

Comment: If you cannot connect to the database, then you cannot gather any metrics from it either. You also wite you suspected the problem was on the python side. Why do you need mysql info then?

Comment: echo=True shows some timing info

Answer (score 0):

you can use echo=True or echo="debug" while creating sqlalchemy engine like below

```
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
```

or

```
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, echo="debug")
```

for more information you can check description of create_engine function of sqlalchemy which is as follows for echo param

```
:param echo=False: if True, the Engine will log all statements
        as well as a ``repr()`` of their parameter lists to the default log
        handler, which defaults to ``sys.stdout`` for output.   If set to the
        string ``"debug"``, result rows will be printed to the standard output
        as well. The ``echo`` attribute of ``Engine`` can be modified at any
        time to turn logging on and off; direct control of logging is also
        available using the standard Python ``logging`` module.

        .. seealso::

            :ref:`dbengine_logging` - further detail on how to configure
            logging.
```

> So echo="debug" will print all the response of particular query and
> echo=True will respond with sql query which will be created by your
> ORM.

**[Edit]**
you can set environment variable as DB_ECHO in env file of your project so that you can turn on and off this setting.